# How to make calls with GSM modem using python

Tags: python, gsm, modem

I am trying to use gsmmodem-new on python to make calls from attached gsm modem. The modem is connected on serial com 1 and the baud rate is set at 115200. Sim card has no PIN code enabled.

I am simply trying to use the example provided by the developers

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""\
Demo: dial a number (simple example using polling to check call status)

Simple demo app that makes a voice call and plays sone DTMF tones (if 
supported by modem)
when the call is answered, and hangs up the call.
It polls the call status to see if the call has been answered

Note: you need to modify the NUMBER variable for this to work
"""

from __future__ import print_function

import sys, time, logging
from hashlib import new

PORT = 'COM1'
BAUDRATE = 115200
NUMBER = '6973233298' # Number to dial - CHANGE THIS TO A REAL NUMBER
PIN = None # SIM card PIN (if any)
waitingForModemToRespondInSeconds = 10

from gsmmodem.modem import GsmModem
from gsmmodem.exceptions import InterruptedException, CommandError

def main():
    if NUMBER == None or NUMBER == '00000':
        print('Error: Please change the NUMBER variable\'s value before 
                    running this example.')
        sys.exit(1)
    print('Initializing modem...')
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s', 
              level=logging.DEBUG)
    modem = GsmModem(PORT, BAUDRATE)
    modem.connect(PIN,waitingForModemToRespondInSeconds)
    print('Waiting for network coverage...')
    modem.waitForNetworkCoverage(30)
    print('Dialing number: {0}'.format(NUMBER))
    call = modem.dial(NUMBER)
    print('Waiting for call to be answered/rejected')
    wasAnswered = False
    while call.active:
        if call.answered:
            wasAnswered = True
            print('Call has been answered; waiting a while...')

            time.sleep(3.0)
            print('Playing DTMF tones...')
            try:
                if call.active: # Call could have been ended by remote party while we waited in the time.sleep() call
                    call.sendDtmfTone('9515999955951')
            except InterruptedException as e:
                # Call was ended during playback
                print('DTMF playback interrupted: {0} ({1} Error {2})'.format(e, e.cause.type, e.cause.code))
            except CommandError as e:
                print('DTMF playback failed: {0}'.format(e))
            finally:
                if call.active: # Call is still active
                    print('Hanging up call...')
                    call.hangup()
                else: # Call is no longer active (remote party ended it)
                    print('Call has been ended by remote party')
        else:
            # Wait a bit and check again
            time.sleep(0.5)
    if not wasAnswered:
        print('Call was not answered by remote party')
    print('Done.')
    modem.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but the process stucks when a connection is trying to be established with the modem. It seems that it cannot connect to the modem in order to proceed to the next steps.

Can someone please help me?